# replace the command 'set' in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

how can I use the command 'set' in the GUI in matlab that it can keep the previous answer and not to replace it with the new one. like for example, when I use a for loop and get more than one output, in the normal matlab code it will keep all outputs and print it in the screen as the following:

```
for i=2:length(contextt)
if ~isequal(co1,co2)
if strcmp(q,pc) || ~ismember(tt1(length(tt1)),tt3)
       fprintf('RKC = { %s , %s }\n',pc,cc)

   set(textA,'string',['RKC = {',pc ,',', cc,'}']);            

end
end
end
```

the result will be the follwoing:

```
 answer = { a0.b0.d6 , a0.c0 }
 answer = { a0.c0 , a0.c0.d5 }
 answer = { a0.c1.b2.d13 , a0.c1.c3 }
```

but in the GUI version, when I type:

```
set(textA,'string',['answer = {',x ,',', m,'}']);
```

it will give me only the last answer means that it updates the answer every time the for loop begins:

```
 answer={a0.d2.c2 , a0.d2.c2.d10}
```

so is there any command in GUI that can keep answers and put each answer in one line like the fprintf does..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new variable that saves the previous result and the new one.

for example:

```
str='';
for i=1:6
str=[str; num2str(i)];
end
```

now when you use set(handle,'string',str) it will show:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: thank you very much for ur support.. but because that I have for loops and if statements in the code ( I did add the part wich related to the output) I don't know how many outputs will be in order to select i...

Comment: I tried your method and it works.. thank you again...but the thing is that each output should contains 2 strings values in the same line.. in my code it makes these two values in two lines..which makes every output bvalue in seperate line...the code is          str={pc , cc};
str1=[str; str1];
        
end
end

end

  end

set(textA,'string',str1);

Comment: In Matlab you can concatenate in one line or in two lines:
     
inLine=[str, ' ' , str];
towLines=[str; str];

if i understood your last comment, you can replace str={pc, cc} with 
str=[pc, ' ', cc]. this will add a space between the two strings.  
best regards.

P.S i found a website that may help you: [link] (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html)